# Overloaded Operator not working properly?

Tags: c++, debugging, operator-overloading, overloading

I am getting an error when I compile my program and am unsure as to how to fix it with the appropriate function to solve this problem. I will post the Main, Header, and CPP file below with the desired outcome following. Any help/tips are appreciated, thank you!

Error I get:

```
Error   C2679   binary '+=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'double'
```

UPDATED:
I have fixed the code to update the "=" operator overload and it is working except 1 line of output.

This is what i get for output:

A: No Name: $0.00

B: Saving: $10000.99

C: Checking: $100.99

---

A: No Name: $10101.98

B: Saving: $10000.99

C: Checking: $100.99

---

A: Joint: $0.00

B: Saving: $10000.99

C: Checking: $100.99

---

A: Saving: $10101.98

B: Saving: $10101.98

C: Checking: $100.99

---

A: Saving: $10302.98

B: Saving: $10302.98

C: Checking: $201.00

---

For some reason the "JOINT" balance comes up as 0 and i am unsure why. it should show as $10101.98

The Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"
using namespace std;
void displayABC(const Account& A,
    const Account& B,
    const Account& C) {
    cout << "A: " << A << endl << "B: " << B << endl
            << "C: " << C << endl << "--------" << endl;
}
int main() {
    Account A;
    Account B("Saving", 10000.99);
    Account C("Checking", 100.99);
    displayABC(A, B, C);
    A = B + C;
    displayABC(A, B, C);
    A = "Joint";
    displayABC(A, B, C);
    A = B += C;
    displayABC(A, B, C);
    A = B += C += 100.01;
    displayABC(A, B, C);
    return 0;
}
```

Source File:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include "Account.h"
using namespace std;

    Account::Account() {
            name_[0] = 0;
            balance_ = 0;
    }
    Account::Account(double balance) {
            name_[0] = 0;
            balance_ = balance;
    }
    Account::Account(const char name[], double balance) {
            strncpy(name_, name, 40);
            name_[40] = 0;
            balance_ = balance;
    }


    void Account::display(bool gotoNewline)const {
            cout << (name_[0] ? name_ : "No Name") << ": $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << balance_;
            if (gotoNewline) cout << endl;
    }

    Account& Account::operator+=(Account& other) {

            balance_ += other.balance_;
            return *this;
    }

    Account& Account::operator=(const Account& ls) {

                    strcpy(name_, ls.name_);

            balance_ = ls.balance_;

            return *this;
     }
     Account operator+(const Account &one, const Account &two) {
            return Account(one.balance_ + two.balance_);
    }

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Account& A) {
            A.display();
            return os;
    }
```

Header File:

```
#ifndef _ACCOUNT_H__
#define _ACCOUNT_H__
#include <iostream>

    class Account {
            char name_[41];
            double balance_;
    public:
            Account();
            Account(double balance);
            Account(const char name[], double balance = 0.0);
            void display(bool gotoNewline = true)const;

            Account& operator+=(Account& other);
            Account& operator=(const Account & other);
            friend Account operator+(const Account &one, const Account    &two);  



    };

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Account& A);
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `+=` operator method to:

```
Account& operator+=(const Account& other);
```

Comment: Ok, that worked! Now the output for the A value is wrong though. It is just "0.00" for them all

Comment: have updated the post above with the 1 error line i now get

Comment: I'm sure if you use a debugger, and step through the code, you will be able to figure it out. Hint: figure out what happens when  A = "Joint"; gets executed.

Comment: It won't keep the balance as before though and i am not sure why.... i think i've been looking too long at the code now

Comment: it takes a name with no balance... i'm not sure where to go from there

Comment: @bp131313 Instead of using char[] in your class, try replacing it with std::string. This may help you out and you wouldn't have to use strncpy() since the std::string class has a defined = operator where you can easily set str1 = str2. Also if your compiler supports it; you should define your 2nd and 3rd constructors as being explicit. You would need to prefix your Constructors' declarations with this keyword in the header file only except for your Default Constructor that takes no parameters.

Comment: @bp131313 - not only does the constructor in question take only a name parameter, with the balance being optional; now all you have to do is to figure out what the balance gets set to, in that case. Did you try to use the debugger, as I suggested; and if not, why not?